# SQL query err_empty_response

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem when executing a simple piece of code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM exercises");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

}
```

The variables on the first line are imported from another file. Everything works until I try to do anything with the $result variable. I can get the result from the database without an error, but as soon as I start doing something with it in an if statement or  a loop (to fetch the results), my page will simply not load, and I get an err_empty_response. I tested it in multiple browsers. Also, some other of these issues on stackoverflow did not seem to have the soultion to the problem.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: How about mysqli_num_rows($result) ? At the moment you mix mysql and mysqli

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do the trick. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How many records contains table excercises? Have you tried to limit number of results?

Comment: Just a few, to test it.